# forever keep restarting sails after every 100s

Tags: node.js, websocket, sails.js, sails.io.js

I have built web socket based application using sails js(v0.11.2) and mysql (5.6.22) with [sails_mysql_live_connect](https://github.com/numtel/sails-mysql-live-select) .

I have set mysql wait_timeout to 100s for GC(Garbage collector) to close any unused open connections.

Due to wait_timeout, mysql is now closing web socket connection to db after 100s and forever restarts sails as db connection has been closed.

I am getting following error in sails every time mysql closes the connection
[image: Error received in sails when mysql closes connection, and then forever restarts sails]

Is there any work around for this without increasing wait_timeout?